# Is Cess a Prefix or a Suffix?

Tags: affixes

My question concerns the following line on wikipedia page the word about [Cess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cess).

> In colonial India it was applied, with a qualifying prefix, to 
>   any taxation, such as irrigation-cess, educational-cess, and the like.

I am confused the word cess, because it is used **after** the words *irrigation* and *education* yet it is called a *pre*fix.

My first initial thoughts were that use of the word prefix was wrong. So I corrected it. And it stayed that way until few days later someone reverted my edit implying that it was obviously wrong since "Prefix" means before so Cess is a prefix. Now I, either, have been making some stupid grave mistakes throughout my life so far or am simply confused.

Answer (score 6):

The passage you quoted says that "-cess" was used *with a qualifying prefix*. That means that "cess" itself is not the prefix. The prefixes cited as examples are "irrigation" and "educational".

Answer (score 3):

I can understand where your confusion comes from.  The writer of the Wikipedia article has a particular style it seems ... and I would probably dispute that in irrigation-cess and education-cess there are any prefixes or suffixes, as those terms are normally understood.

A suffix or prefix is a fixed set of terms (in-, un-, non-, -ness, -dom, etc) that are used to create new words in English, whereas education and irrigation are just what they are - adjectival descriptions of each type of "cess".

So I don't think you're especially confused, or guilty of making stupid life-long linguistic mistakes!